# Button (onclick) problems it works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, cross-browser

I am working on a project and I have a simple local function call being fired from an onClick property on a button element. It is pretty simple and it works fine Chrome but for some reason it just causes a refresh in Firefox. I have placed some logs and it seems like the function isn't failing it is not even getting called at all. The function is a simple method aggregation function, the other methods are just string validation methods. I have checked the network tab and I a getting an unusual amount of calls in Firefox that I am not seeing in Chrome. Any ideas?

```
<button 
   className="btn btn-accent btn-block" 
   id="loginBtn"
   data-testid="validate-button"
   onClick={validateUser}
>
   {' '}
   Continue
</button>
```

Comment: Can you add the `validateUser` function to your question ? also if possible, screen shot of the network tap ?

Comment: Looks like a [firefox specific bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8554) you can use [preventDefault](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in the click handler.